# Laravel 6: Select Distinct on one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, image

I´M TRYNG to get one image for each product, but if the product has 3 images it return 3 instances of one product with different pictures

```
mobimages
idimage | idproduto | prodimage |
1       | 2         | xxxxx.png |
2       | 2         | yyyy.png  |
3       | 2         | zzzzz.png |

produtos
id      | marca       | modelo |
1       | Huawei      | P30    |
2       | Samsung     | A20    |
3       | Xiaomi      | Note7  |
```

controller

```
 $produtos = DB::table('produtos')
        ->join('mobimages', 'mobimages.idproduto', '=', 'produtos.id')
        ->select('produtos.*', 'mobimages.prodimage')->distinct('mobimages.prodimage')->get();
```

i want de following result

```
id  | marca | modelo | prodimage |
2   |samsung|A20     | xxxx.png  |
```

not

```
 id  | marca | modelo | prodimage |
 2   |samsung|A20     | xxxx.png  |
 2   |samsung|A20     | yyyy.png  |
 2   |samsung|A20     | zzzzz.png  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupBy`

```
 $produtos = DB::table('produtos')
        ->join('mobimages', 'mobimages.idproduto', '=', 'produtos.id')
        ->select('produtos.*', 'mobimages.prodimage')
        ->groupBy('produtos.id')
        ->get();
```

**Change config/databases.php -> mysql array i change strict => true , to strict => false and you get an answer**

Comment: when i use groupBy() return the same thing as distinct()

Comment: first a get an error but in config/databases.php -> mysql array i change strict  => true , to  strict  => false and i get an answer

Comment: Great please mark as verified this answer thank you

Comment: but the answer i haved when i use groupBy() return the same thing as distinct()

Comment: I update my answer..now you can accept this because other people can easily refer this answer thank you

Comment: i change groupBy('mobimages.idimage') to  groupBy('produtos.id') and it works correctly

Comment: please give upvote this answer big thanx..@leorodriguez